# Dealing the measurement units

Tags: android

Every country uses own measurement units, for example people in US measure temperature in F however Canada and most European countries in C. Same is applied for measurement weight, distance and so on.
I define measurement units in my application as

```
<string-array name="measure_units">
    <item>lb</item>
    <item>oz</item>
    <item>cwt</item>
    <item>ft</item>
    <item>yd</item>
```

for default locale and then for France I define something like

```
<string-array name="measure_units">
    <item>kg</item>
    <item>ml</item>
    <item>tn</item>
    <item>dm</item>
    <item>m</item>
```

So far so good, however it is a huge work to define the values for every country considering tons of duplicates. So I am thinking to introduce 2-4 basic measurement systems and specify values only for them, but how to implement it for Android? Is there any measurement systems mapping embedded in the OS? If there is no such functionality how do you deal with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

SO this kind of thing is part of localization of an app.  Generally the rule is-  use one system internally in your app (generally metric, but anything will work).  Convert to local units only right before display or right after data is input, never store data in anything but your internal format.

You might be able to find a library to do this for you, but its not built into Android or Java.  Typically though you don't map every language to a length, temperature, etc.  You do just what you suggested-  build a couple of linked choices, and map Locales to a specific set of choices.  If you pick metric as your default, you only need to do overrides for 2 or 3 countries-  pretty much everyone uses metric.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion.

First store the values in international units. (Distance in m, Weight in kg, Temperature in C . . . etc). Then use some methods to convert international units to other units. When ever you need non-international units, use those methods to get the converted values. You can use an if statement or a switch to get the values accordingly.

As an example

```
if(/*international unit ?*/){
    Log.D("International unit : ", temperature + "C");
}else{
    Log.D("Non - International unit : ", getTemperatureInFahrenheit(temperature) + "F");
}

float getTemperatureInFahrenheit(float celsius){
    return ((celsius * 9 / 5.0) + 32)
}
```

Comment: These unit systems are called **metric** (for "international") and **imperial** (for "non international").

Comment: My use case is simpler, I do not do any calculations, my measurement system is just for presentation purpose. Let's say person is writing some diary and want to put something today I ran one mile in US and I ran 1.5km in France. However my user doesn't do free typing, he/she just fills some table selecting predefined activities and putting numeral data with accompanied units. I am thinking t give a user option to fill in own units system and then just use it. It will allow to use hybrid systems too.

Comment: My suggestion is just save the values in metric format. You need calculations only for converting imperials to metrics and metrics to imperials. I think you have to format the string before presenting.


Thanks @ArtooDetoo for your information.

Comment: I'd also do so. Just use a "scaling factor", i.e.: 1 kilometer =
0.621371192 miles (multiply km by this "magic number" and you're done)

Comment: I guess he need both ways, 1Km = 0.621371192 miles and 1mile = 1.609344 kilometers. Because he is planing to let the user to select the unit in the filling form and display in different units in different languages.